# How To Pin Two Object in Cinema 4D r19

Tags: texture, cinema4d

How To Pin Two Object in Cinema 4D r19 version, in cinema 4d r19 the pin material tag is not available. How to pin a object and texture without using pin material tag.

Thanks.